# How to get output from NodeRed Mysql node

Tags: mysql, node-red

I want to get out put from NodeRed mysql node.

Here image of connection : 
[image]

Select Query is :

```
msg.topic = "SELECT * t.TableID FROM booking t where t.bookingdate='"+formattedDate+"' and t.TableID = 3";
```

Output i am trying to get:

```
if(msg.payload.TableID ==3){
    var id = "15";
 var message = "Front Desk";
msg.topic = "INSERT INTO tableMessage(TableID, MESSAGE) VALUES ('"+id+"' ,'"+message+"')";

return msg;
}
```

Question is `msg.payload.TableID ==3` is it right? is it right way to read out put from Mysql node

Select query are tested working fine.
but this condition not working for me.

any one help me how to retrieve data from mysql node.

Thanks

Comment: what is the point of the image? Things happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output from the mysql node is an array of rows so your test should be something like this:

```
if (msg.payload[0].TableID ==3) {
...
```

EDIT:
You can test if no results were returned by testing the content of *msg.payload*

```
if (!msg.payload) {
  //no results
} else if (msg.payload[0].TableID == 3) {
  //results
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply , it works fine.  Mysql node only return if query true. if not null,  but i want to use else function also if this if function not true, any idea how can do it.